# React native button need twice click to change state

Tags: react-native, state

when i click on "Show Element" button, I want change state to true
and when i click on "Hide Element" button, I want change state to false

but when i click on "Show Element" button at first time it don't change to true and there is need i click on button second time for change state to true. and it's same when i click on "Hide Element" button

here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform, AsyncStorage, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Button  } from 'react-native'

class Base extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isForShowVar: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button
            style={{marginTop:50, width:150}}
            title="Hide Element"
            onPress={()=>{ alert(this.state.isForShowVar); this.setState({isForShowVar: false});  }}
          />  
          <Button
            style={{marginTop:50, width:150}}
            title="Show Element"
            onPress={()=>{ alert(this.state.isForShowVar); this.setState({isForShowVar: true});  }}
          />  
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Base;
```

you can test code in [here](https://snack.expo.io/@mojtaba.expo/card.actions?name=Card.Actions&description=https%3A%2F%2Fcallstack.github.io%2Freact-native-paper%2Fcard-actions.html&code=import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%27react%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20Card%2C%20Button%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native-paper%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20MyComponent%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%3CCard%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CCard.Actions%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CButton%3ECancel%3C%2FButton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CButton%3EOk%3C%2FButton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FCard.Actions%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FCard%3E%0A)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20MyComponent%3B&dependencies=react-native-paper)

how can change state when i click on button at first time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, this happens because you read `isForShowVar` before set. Anyway also if you move alert after `this.setState` you got the old value because `this.setState` is async. But you can use `this.setState` callback like this:

```
this.setState({isForShowVar: true}, () => {
   alert(this.state.isForShowVar); 
});
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/xkzA4s!Uu) your code modified.

Comment: thanks for your solution, i just used alert to show what happening when i click on button, i updated my question, please chack the link: https://snack.expo.io/@mojtaba.expo/card.actions

Comment: Sorry but I don't undestand. You made a question. I answered. Is the answer correct? If yes, mark it as valid. Then, if you want more you can ask me other things here. Anyway, your new example is not clear. You already passed `this.state.isForShowVar` as props to `FadeInOut` component...